# in redux-react on initial component render dispatched and state is changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-usememo

I have created a login component, and there is a state **Auth** with redux

that and reducer to update the **Auth** state (initally it is set as FALSE)

but on initial render dispatch is called 4 times and state is updated to TRUE

i have tried useMemo, but not sure how exacltly use it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reducer-ijhj5?file=/src/Components/LoginComponent.js

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a bug

```
<button onClick={() => memoziedLogin}>Login</button>
```

The `memoziedLogin` should be called like `memoziedLogin()`. See below bellow

```
<button onClick={() => memoziedLogin()}>Login</button>
```

Comment: ok @moshfiqrony, but still the same,
tried what you said, getting the things rendered on load and dispatched the action and state changed on initial render

Comment: Which action is calling?

Comment: `const memoziedLogin = useMemo(() => {
    dispatch(LoginAction());
  }, []);` this is the event attached to button      
`<button onClick={() => memoziedLogin()}>Login</button>`
now even before clicking button , on initial render this memoziedLogin is called which intern LoginAction is called